# How to edit this JS code so to add chars in the hashed text instead of only numbers

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to avoid md5 because it is a big function

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  var hash = 0, i, chr, len;
  if (this.length == 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
    chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  return hash;
};
```

as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/h0ef92Lu/

and it creates a xxxxxxxxxx (10) digits hash. My problem is that statistically if I have 9999999999 rows, the next one will be duplicated and I don't want duplicates. So, I thought of adding chars with the numbers.

My question is how to do it, is it applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head you can use something like this

```
 return hash + parseInt(time.getTime()).toString(36).toUpperCase();
```

It would keep your ID unique 99.99% of the times

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that statistically if I have 9999999999 rows, the next one will be duplicated and I don't want duplicates.

You can get duplicates with as few as two rows. For example, using your hash function, the following will output `2095` both times:

```
alert("AP".hashCode());
alert("B1".hashCode());
```

Hashes, by their nature, throw away data from the input, so you cannot avoid duplicates unless you know exactly which data is superfluous. That is called [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), but you cannot do perfect hashing unless you know in advance all the possible inputs you could need to hash.

Otherwise, you could make your hash code longer or more complicated to make duplicates rarer, but it won't guarantee avoidance of duplicates unless the hash is at least as long as the information content of any of the possible inputs, and then there is no point in hashing it at all.

It sounds to me like hashing is not the right technique for solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please tell me, what if I still use md5? Are my chances better for uniqueness?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos MD5 has a high chance of uniqueness both because it is longer and because it distributes changes better (changing a single bit in the input re-randomizes the entire hash). However, MD5 is completely unsafe against *deliberate* collision attacks. It depends what you want to do with it: MD5 will be fine if you simply want a high probability of uniqueness on random data, but it is unsuitable if you depend on the uniqueness for security, because users could design data to deliberately collide hashes to break that security. If you need a hash for security look to SHA-256 or SHA-512.

Comment: I see, however it is not a security thing, what I am doing is to keep as small as possible the kb and hashing a text to save it in database, but it has to be unique. Is there any possibility of adding more digits to the existing maybe?

Comment: If it is for a database, then shouldn't you do it on the PHP rather than JavaScript side? Anyway, it is impossible to get a hash which is small and guaranteed unique. MD5 is *quite* small and *probably* unique, so it may be the best you'll get.

Comment: this is a good point, but what I do is I get screen size and things like this and send it as md5 rather than all that text